# Is stashing panel in gitkraken only for local stashes?

Tags: git, gitkraken

I'm new to gitkraken (and git in general) and I don't understand if in the stash panel only local stashes are shown or if I can see remote stashes too (I heard they are a thing but I'm still confused about that). Sorry for the question and thanks in advance!

Comment: Stashes always are local.

Comment: This might be a better fit over on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ At least for research purposes.

Comment: No such thing as remote stashes.